# How to input multiple query to MySQL in JAVA?

Tags: java, mysql, arrays, netbeans

I want to enter data from the input variable array to MySQL but the only successful array is first enter the CPU data. How do I enter all the queries I create?

```
try {
    String price = Text.getText();
    String CPU = String.valueOf(CBCPU.getSelectedItem());
    String mobo = String.valueOf(CBmobo.getSelectedItem());
    String RAM = String.valueOf(CBRAM.getSelectedItem());
    String VGA = String.valueOf(CBVGA.getSelectedItem());
    Connection c=buka_koneksi();
    Statement s= c.createStatement();
    String hapus = "DELETE FROM `operasi`";
    String[] input = {"INSERT INTO `operasi`(`id`,`nama_barang`,`harga`) "
        + "SELECT `id`,`merkcpu`,`harga` FROM cpulist WHERE merkcpu='"+CPU+"';",
        "INSERT INTO `operasi`(`id`,`nama_barang`,`harga`) "
        + "SELECT `id`,`motherboard`,`harga` FROM mobooo WHERE motherboard='"+mobo+"';",
        "INSERT INTO `operasi`(`id`,`nama_barang`,`harga`) "
        + "SELECT `id`,`ram`,`harga` FROM ram WHERE ram='"+RAM+"';",
        "INSERT INTO `operasi`(`id`,`nama_barang`,`harga`) "
        + "SELECT `id`,`vga`,`harga` FROM vga WHERE vga='"+VGA+"';"};
    s.executeUpdate(hapus);
    for (String inputkan : input) {
        s.executeUpdate(inputkan.trim());
    }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "SUKSES");
} catch (Exception e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please have a look at [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [Asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).

Comment: Do you get any exceptions showing? and are you sure that the select criteria are returning rows?

Comment: no my program just that